# Hide and Show depending on value

Tags: javascript, php, show-hide

Does anyone know how to hide and show options under `select`-tag depending on a certain value from database?

Here's what I did but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    var a = <?php echo $row["status"]; ?>
    if(a == 'To be check' || a == 'Endorsed By IT') {
        $("#new").show();
    } else
        $("#new").hide();   
    </script>
```

Here's what's under `#new`:

```
<div id="new">
    <select name="status">
        <option value="Request">Request</option>
        <option value="Upload">Upload</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap your script code in document ready handler. `$(document).ready(function() {
    });`

Comment: try with  var a = '<?php echo $row["status"]; ?>'

Comment: You will need jQuery

Comment: In you question you ask to hide or show **options** inside a `select` tag depending on values, but on your code you hide or show a whole `div` element that has a `select` element as child. What exactly do you want? Regarding your question, do you get any log errors? Have you loaded jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

As of your problem [b0s3 has the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30434236/1456376). Besides that, I would recommend a different way to handle this problem:

Try to *modify the HTML markup* while rendering instead of your altering your JavaScript:

```
<div id="new" <?print ( in_array($row["status"], array('To be check', 'Endorsed By IT')) ? 'class="active"' : ''); ?>
    […]
</div>
```

You can use a CSS class like:

```
#new { display: none; }
#new.active { display: block; }
```

You can still alter the visibility later by using:

```
document.getElementById('new').classList.toggle('active'); // vanilla JS
$('#new').toggleClass('active'); // jQuery
```

The advantages are:

- The element is hidden right away and won't be visible to the user if your page loads slowly (for whatever reason).
- The JavaScript code could be kept and maintained separately from your template, as it doesn't have to be modified by PHP.

Comment: No need for jquery. `PHP` and `css` will do it all. +1 .

Answer (score 1):

Missing the quotes. `$row["status"]` contains string. You should add the quotes properly.

```
<script>
    var a = '<?php echo $row["status"]; ?>'; // missing the quotes here
    if(a == 'To be check' || a == 'Endorsed By IT')
    {
        $("#new").show();
    }
    else
        $("#new").hide();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show/hide div using javascript, you can write like :

```
<script>
        var a = '<?php echo $row["status"]; ?>';
        if(a == 'To be check' || a == 'Endorsed By IT')
        {
            document.getElementById(new).style.display = 'block';
        }
        else
            document.getElementById(new).style.display = 'none';

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<script>
 var a = '<?php echo $row["status"]; ?>';
 if(a == 'To be check' || a == 'Endorsed By IT')
 {
 document.getElementById("new").style.display = 'block';
 }
 else
 {
 document.getElementById("new").style.display = 'none';
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

i guess you need to do it write condition in document ready method

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var a = '<?php echo $row["status"]; ?>'; // missing the quotes here
    if(a == 'To be check')
     {
         $("#new").show();
     }
     else
         $("#new").hide();
})
```